# Read XElement Fragment from xml file to XElement Element

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have xml fragment in an xml-File. The fragment has tags with namespace.

How can I read that xml fragment, which represent exactly an XElement element ?

```
    <node id="n0::n0">
  <data key="d6">
    <y:ShapeNode>
      <y:Geometry height="91.44" width="59.49119999999999" x="364.256180835285" y="-698.4404365079365"/>
      <y:Fill color="#FFCC00" transparent="false"/>
      <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
      <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="12" fontStyle="plain" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="18.701171875" modelName="internal" modelPosition="t" textColor="#000000" visible="true" width="48.677734375" x="5.406732812499968" y="4.0">MELEIN</y:NodeLabel>
      <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="12" fontStyle="plain" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="18.701171875" modelName="custom" textColor="#000000" visible="true" width="27.35546875" x="16.067865624999968" y="20.843814062500087">8,00<y:LabelModel>
          <y:SmartNodeLabelModel distance="4.0"/>
        </y:LabelModel>
        <y:ModelParameter>
          <y:SmartNodeLabelModelParameter labelRatioX="0.0" labelRatioY="-0.5" nodeRatioX="0.0" nodeRatioY="-0.2720492775317138" offsetX="0.0" offsetY="0.0" upX="0.0" upY="-1.0"/>
        </y:ModelParameter>
      </y:NodeLabel>
      <y:Shape type="rectangle"/>
    </y:ShapeNode>
  </data>
</node>
```

I tried a lot of different ways the last one nearly comes to the target

```
        var mngr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(new System.Xml.NameTable());
    mngr.AddNamespace(string.Empty, "urn: ignore"); // or proper URL
    mngr.AddNamespace("y", "urn:ignore"); // or proper URL
    var parserContext = new System.Xml.XmlParserContext(null, mngr, null, System.Xml.XmlSpace.None, null);

    var txtReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader("block.graphml", System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext);
    var ele = XElement.Load(txtReader);
```

but it crashes in the last line with `System.InvalidOperationException`

Is there any easy way to import xml fragment to an existing xelement?
I would prefer the way `XElement.load("block.graphml");` This didn't work at all.

Thanks for your tips

Comment: You're close, but your `XmlTextReader` is expecting the XML string not a path to the XML string.

Comment: Thank, your hint solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XElement element = XElement.Parse("<Root xmlns:y=\"www.mynamespace.com\"></Root>");

            element.Add(input);

        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  All this will do is add a load of text inside `Root`.  You'll end up with  something like `<Root xmlns:y="www.mynamespace.com"> &lt;node id="n0::n0"&gt; ...`.

Comment: No I didn't try, I 'am using now a streamreader to get the text in, then it was working. But your way seems to be a lot shorter. When I read in my next xml fragment I'll try it.